# Bower installed components that not defined in bower.json to asp.net 5 application

Tags: asp.net, bower, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, bower-install

I had a problem when trying install client packages using Bower in ASP.NET 5 application. I defined some packages I want to install to my application in *bower.json* file, like this:

```
 {
  "name": "bower",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "1.11.2",
    "modernizr": "2.8.3",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.4",
    "jquery.uniform": "2.1.2",
    "fluidbox": "1.4.3",
    "owl-carousel": "1.3.2",
    "photo.swipe": "4.0.8",
    "magnific-popup": "1.0.0",
    "slippry": "1.2.9",
    "fastclick": "1.0.6",
    "imagesloaded": "3.1.8",
    "jquery-validate": "1.13.1",
    "fitvids": "1.1.0",
    "jquery-gridrotator": "0.1.0" }
```

After saving, I saw in the hidden *bower_components* folder there were some other packages I didn't defined in the bower.json file, like this:

[image]

After running grunt task, I saw some strange packages installed to my application.

[image]

My simple gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        bower: {
            install: {
                options: {
                    targetDir: "wwwroot/lib",
                    layout: "byComponent",
                    cleanTargetDir: true
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask("default", ["bower:install"]);

    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-bower-task");
};
```

So, how can I only install packages I want to my ASP.NET 5 application? Thank you so much.

Comment: `imagesloaded` seems to depend on `eventie` and `eventEmitter`, so that explains those two, but I'm unable to reproduce the issue with the other extra packages starting from a new web project.

Answer (score 0):

They are dependencies installed by bower by example Masonry use this dependencies

```
{
  "name": "masonry",
  "version": "3.3.0",
  "description": "Cascading grid layout library",
  "main": "masonry.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "get-size": "~1.2.2",
    "outlayer": "~1.4.0",
    "fizzy-ui-utils": "~1.0.1"
  }
}
```

I recomend you to use the dest,js_dest, css_dest and font_dest to split the files by type and set the option keepExpandedHierarchy to false something like this

```
           {
                dest: "wwwroot/lib",
                js_dest: "wwwroot/lib/js",
                css_dest: "wwwroot/lib/css",
                fonts_dest: "wwwroot/lib/font",
                options: {
                    keepExpandedHierarchy: false
                }
            }
```

and use some module like includeSource to add all the files in your cshtml file

```
includeSource: {
            layout: {
                files: {
                    'Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml': 'Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml'
                }
            },
            options: {
                basePath: "wwwroot/lib/js",
                baseUrl: '~/lib/',
            }
        }
```

and you must add the markup in your page

```
 <!-- include: "type": "js", "files":"**/*.js", "ordering": "top-down" -->
    <!-- /include -->
```

hope it helps